# How can I constrain a method that takes an Action<T> to only allow delegates from a specific class

Tags: c#, delegates

If I have a method signature like this;

```
public void Execute(Action<T> action) {
    ...
}
```

but I want to constrain it so that the supplied 'action' only comes from the class 'MyActions', how can this be achieved in c#?

---

In order to try and make it clearer;

For example I have a class called MyActions;

```
public class MyActions {
    public void FirstAction<T>(T item) {
        ...
    }

    public void SecondAction<T>(T item) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have the above method and I want it so that the only actions that the method will accept are those from this class.

I do not want it to be possible for anyone to supply an arbitrary action, they must come from the class 'MyActions'.

Can it be done?

Regards,

Ryan.

Comment: why? it is not possible.

Comment: If it's your signature, why can't you write `public void Execute(MyActions action){...}`?

Comment: What does it mean: "action comes from the class `MyActions`"? What the word "comes" means in this context?

Comment: Could you explain why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: Your update still doesn't explain *why* you want to do that. Could you clarify that?

Comment: If u want to make a method available to only one class the proper thing to do is make said method a private member of said class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make clear your intent that you want to accept only members of `MyActions` would be something like:

```
public void Execute(Func<MyActions, Action<T>> actionSelector)
```

You could then call it like

```
Execute(actions => actions.SomeAction);
```

Of course, this works only if the methods (or delegate properties) of `MyActions` are not static.

And like I said, this makes your intent clear, but doesn't actually constraint the methods, someone could still call your method like:

```
Execute(ignored => otherAction);
```

In general this seems to me like a weird thing to want.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's weird?  I want to define the interface of a method to take some delegate drawn from a finite set of delegates.  Surely this is a common thing to do.  I can't help but feel there's some obvious design pattern I'm missing here.

Comment: Because that's not delegates are meant for. That restriction feels awfully artificial, why can't I put my own delegate into that method? And if you want to have a parameter limited to a fixed set of options, you can use an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public sealed class MyActions <T> where T:new()
{ 
    public enum Methods { First, Second }  

    static Action<T>[] MethodsArray = { Method1, Method2 };
    public virtual void Execute(T value, Methods methods = Methods.First)
    {
        MethodsArray[(int) methods].Invoke(value);
    }
    private void Method1(T value) {}
    private void Method2(T value) {}

}

//public class MiActionsSeconds<T> : MyActions <T>    where T:new()
// {
//     public override void Execute( T value, Methods methods = Methods.Second )
//     {
//         base.Execute( value, methods );
//     }
// }

public class Foo<T>  where T:new()
{
    public void Execute(MyActions<T> instance, MyActions<T>.Methods methods = Methods.First)
    {
        instance.Execute( default( T ) );
        instance.Execute( default( T ), MyActions<T>.Methods.Second );
    }

    public void Test()
    {
      //  Execute( new MiActionsSeconds<T>( ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I meant.  T can be anything, the Action<T> has to be specified in the class 'MyActions', see my improved question for clarity.

Comment: I think that is the nearest way that can be done what you are asking for. You can use reflection but this should be at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using Reflection however it would hurt performance and I don't recommend it as it is just plain a bad idea. I think you should try a less specific question; how about telling us what you want to achieve that has led you down this path and maybe we can help you accomplish that another way.

Comment: That's not really what I'm after, my solution works, however ANY Action<T> can be supplied as a parameter and I want to force the supplied Action<T> to be from some finite set.  See my improved question for details.

Answer (score 0):

A big problem with this is that once you get `Action<...> foo = MyActions.FirstAction` to pass into `Execute` you have retrieved a value, and its type is simply `Action<...>`. There is nothing in the type that shows it was previously stored in a reference in `MyActions`. You can check to see if `MyActions` contains the action being passed by comparing the references, but that's a runtime check.

A partial way to put this information in the type is to have a `MyAction` class that everything in `MyActions` derives from. Then you can restrict `Execute` to take `MyAction` instances. However, a user could just as easily as you create their own `MyAction` subclass.

This smells like unnecessary exposure of internals: if only that small set of `Action`s work, then why do you ask the user for an `Action`? An `enum` that allows the user to specify intent or just several different `Execute` methods makes more sense.