# Is it possible to constrain a delegate to a member of a type?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'd like to constrain a delegate to a member of a type. For example...

```
class Foo {
    public virtual void Bar() {}
}
class Baz : Foo {
    public override void Bar() {
        this.BarAndMore(base.Bar);
    }
}
delegate void FooMemberDelegate(); // Can I restrict this so `FooMemberDelegate`s can only be assigned to members of Foo
static class Extensions {
    public static void BarAndMore(this Foo foo, FooMemberDelegate fooMemberDelegate) {
        // Other stuff
        fooMemberDelegate();
        // More stuff
    }
}
```

EDIT: Seems to be a duplicate of [How can I constrain a method that takes an Action<T> to only allow delegates from a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457661/how-can-i-constrain-a-method-that-takes-an-actiont-to-only-allow-delegates-fro?rq=1)

Comment: Sounds like [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve instead?

Comment: I'm trying to constrain the usage of a library I'm finishing up. The issue is that a common case where my library might be used is a situation where `Baz` has to inherit from `Foo`, so I have to take the extension method workaround.

Comment: For context, here's the section of my library where I'd like to constrain the `baseSaveChanges` argument. EDIT: Ooops didn't actually post the link https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers/blob/master/EntityFramework.Triggers/Extensions.cs#L92

Comment: And if you're curious, the common situation is that the user's `DbContext` class inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` so the user can get all that good Identity library stuff.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear still why do you need this but there is no compile time way to prevent this, if you're interested, you could do this runtime by inspecting the `Delegate.Method` property and throw exceptions if doesn't satisfy your needs.